# Как подключить swagger ui?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, swagger

Я сделал по инструкции подключил swagger к asp.net, и я зайдя по swagger/v1/swagger.json, вижу json, с моими методами.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {

        services.AddControllersWithViews();
        services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "My API", Version = "v1" });
        });

        services.AddSingleton<IUserService, UserService>();

        services.AddAuthentication(x =>
        {
            x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
       .AddJwtBearer(x =>
       {
           x.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
           x.SaveToken = true;
           x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
           {
               ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
               IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("**")),
               ValidateIssuer = false,
               ValidateAudience = false,
           };
       });

        services.AddMvcCore()
            .AddNewtonsoftJson();

    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseSpaStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseSwagger();
        app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Test API V1");
            c.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;
        });


        app.UseCors(x => x
            .AllowAnyOrigin()
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            .AllowAnyHeader());

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();


        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
```

Но как мне подключить чтобы было UI? а не просто  json?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swagger UI - отдельный статичный веб проект, задачи которого показать спецификацию в user friendly интерфейсе. Если поискать просторы интернета то можно найти, бесплатную версию сайта, нужно будет лишь заменить yaml file в проекте.

Comment: Просто у меня нету как раз этих файлов.

Comment: @chilo5432 скачайте тут https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui